# jQuery: Most efficient way of dealing with many many images

Tags: jquery, image, performance

I have a situation where im not sure on the best way forward.

I have a gallery and an option to view via pages or to view all one on page.

The problem deals with viewing them all one one page. There can be many many images. 1000+.

Now straight away I thought either using the lazy load jquery plugin or using ajax that retrieves new images and inserts them as you scroll. (My thought is that ajax is better as using a lazy load plugin means there are still going to be 1000+ DOM elements that it has to track and manipulate etc?) Anyway the problem isnt direct related to them.

If it was just that then I would have implemented the ajax method.

The problem lies in that on the page I have 2 features.

A button to shuffle all the images on the page. So if there are lots of images you can click the button and it shuffles the display.

A slider to change between 3 set sizes to view them as small medium or large (large is default view, when the scaling has finished it replaces the image src which a premade image that fits the new dimensions)).

The problem is, if I use Ajax im not sure how I can deal with the shuffle as the shuffle will just re-arranging the images currently in the DOM (which is how its working now, just re-arranging the order of the html.

Second problem is with the slider.....however I assume I could just set it so that when they reduce in side it will detect if there is any space left on the page and if so ajax call the next section to fill in the gap...

Also my tests using the lazy load method is that when shuffling, if there are too many images on the page the page locks up for a few seconds while it tries to shuffle 1000+ images. (the lazy load has other problems such as when the new shuffled items come into view the images are not loaded and also same when the slider is used an new images come into view, they are not loaded...but this is a problem or settings to do with the lazy load itself)

Maybe im missing something, or there is an alternative im not aware of.

So the question really is.

What would be the best way / the most efficient way as to not make the browser choke, to deal with a large amount of images keeping the functionally of being able to shuffle and change the scale of the images.

Comment: What comes to mind is having loaded beforehand all images(small,medium,large) in Local Storage. When is come to show them  just reading them from Local Storage.

Comment: @KiaMorot, localstorage is too slow and too limited in size for the purpose. LS is about 5Mb in `UTF16/UCS2` and I don't think is enough for 1000+ images in 3 versions.

Comment: I really cannot see what you are asking. Either it's a very broad question that cannot be answered in one or two paragraphs, or it's very specific to your situation. There also seem to be several questions at once.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan Even slower than getting them from the server? I really can't believe that.

Comment: Preloading all the images certainly is not an option, that would mean 500MB+ . Each image in the "large" view is approximately 500KB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I know of course that all I'll say can be highly debatable or incomplete and probably influenced by my own background, but I'm just trying to give you some ideas to a really broad question.*

I wouldn't discard at all an ajax solution, even if you need to realize those features.

If the user press the shuffle button, you might just show a loader and ask via ajax a json with the full list of images shuffled on server side, e.g.

```
{
   "images" : [
      321,94,566,302,729,136... 
   ]
}
```

then, when the json has been received, use a chunk of first *n* elements of the array to preload and insert on the document first *n* images.

```
     <img src="/high-res/321.jpg" />
     <img src="/high-res/94.jpg" />
     <img src="/high-res/566.jpg" />
     ...
```

About the slider:

> ...large is default view

In this specific scenario you won't really need to also load the medium-res and the low-res version of the same resources: just scale the hi-res images (via css, `transform: scale(...)`).

The real problem with this approach is that you're going to penalize mobile devices, so if you need to support them, my approach could be to previously check for small viewports and - on mobile devices - I would always send instead low-res resolution images, with no possibilities of scaling (think this as a *graceful degradation* or your app).

When user scroll you'll start to read next chunk of array elements (you already have, when you shuffled elements) and create the DOM structure with the new images. The size of the chunk could be adjusted according to the resolution you're currently using:

e.g. for hi-res images use a small set of images to preload. On mobile devices I may pre-load more elements at once, but in that case I would not use the scroll event: I'd prefer to show instead a "load more" button

Comment: Thanks Fabrizio, your answer pretty much addresses everything perfectly, I did not think about shuffling server side and storing the list, and that I think is the thing I was looking for. The reason I switched for the image size that matched the current size is that using smaller file sized images seemed to help out the browser. As for mobiles im creating a mobile specific version of the site.

Comment: Just one thing I thought of, lets say the user scrolled to the end of the list, so that every image had been called for and loaded into the html. If the user was to click on shuffle now, that would mean that all 1000+ images would be removed and then reinserted. Would this high amount of html addition cause the browser to freeze?

Comment: good point: my first idea is to obtain a new array, loop over the images and sequentially change only the `src` attribute. Probably it's better than removing and re-appending nodes 1000 times. Anyway this need some performance testing

Comment: Another good idea!. Also because all the images would have loaded, does that now mean that it should be almost instant and no browser freezing?, as all the images have already been downloaded, they are just now being showing in a different location